# How to check certain chars in string in C?

Tags: c, string

Suppose ,I have to use **only one** string function and check if the string input by user contains **all the chars** a,e,i,o,u ...how do I do it?
(the chars mentioned above need not be contagious in the string input by user.)
Please help.

Comment: Show your efforts so far. SO is not a code-for-me-service....

Comment: Use `strchr` ?..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the function `strchr`

```
char *strchr(const char *str, int c)
```

This function searches for the first occurrence of the character `c` (an unsigned char) in the string pointed to by the argument str.
If the character `c` is not present then `null` is returned.

One of the possible implementation is shown here -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define  SIZE 5
int main ()
{
    char toCheck[5] = {'a','e','i','o','u'}; 
      // Array of characters required in the string.
    char userstring[25]; // User String
    int i;
    printf("Enter your string : \n");
    scanf("%s",userstring);

    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++ ){
         if(strchr(userstring,toCheck[i])==NULL) 
             break;
     }
    if(i==SIZE)
         printf("All Required Characters present");  
    else printf("All Required Characters not present");

    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool containsAll(const char *input, const char *contains){
    bool check[256] = { false };
    while(*input){
        check[(unsigned char)*input++] = true;
    }
    while(*contains){
        if(!check[(unsigned char)*contains++])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main(void){
    char input[256];
    fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin);
    input[strcspn(input, "\n")] = 0;
    if(containsAll(input, "aeiuo"))//"aeiuo\n"
        puts("yes");
    else
        puts("no");
}
```